# Change the value of data,but the data is not updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Multilayer nested about Vue data like this:

```
out:{
   arr:[
        {a:1}
       ]
}
```

When I change the value using `this.out.arr[0] = {a:2}`, the view is not updated. But if my code is `this.out.arr[0].a = 2;`, the view is updated.

Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjGXrB)!

You can comment and uncomment code in the method `changeA` to see the different results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just the standard caveat around updating arrays via indices:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Vue can't detect changes made to an array by directly assigning a value to an index.

So instead of this:

```js
this.out.arr[0] = {a:2}
```

... you'd need to use this:

```js
this.$set(this.out.arr, 0, {a: 2})
```

**Update:**

To understand the difference between the two cases mentioned in the question it might help to write them out in full.

```js
this.out.arr[0] = {a:2}

// ... is equivalent to ...

const arr = this.out.arr // read
arr[0] = {a: 2}          // write
```

Whereas:

```js
this.out.arr[0].a = 2

// ... is equivalent to ...

const obj = this.out.arr[0] // read
obj.a = 2                   // write
```

In the two examples above I've split up the read and write parts of the expressions. Reading values using an array index isn't a problem, just writing. The first example tries to write the `0` property of `arr`, which violates the Vue indices caveat. The second example tries to write to the `a` property of `obj`, which doesn't feature an array index so has no such problem.

Comment: thanks for your attention,but I don't know if you visit my demo link,the fact is that it can update through index...

Comment: @Perhaps In your second example, `this.out.arr[0].a = 2;`, the index is being used to *get* the object at index 0. The `a` property of this object is reactive and can be set no problem. We're modifying an object within the array, not the array itself. The problem occurs when trying to *set* the value using an array index, as in `this.out.arr[0] = {a:2}`. That is trying to change the array itself and runs into the problem mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Above @skirtle answer is the correct way to update vue data ! In vue documentation , it said

> For example, when you set vm.someData = 'new value', the component will not re-render immediately. It will update in the next “tick”, when the queue is flushed.

So , setting directly by index will not update dom immediately .... you need to do forceUpdate

```
  this.out.arr[0] = {a:2}; // can not updated
  this.$nextTick(function () {        
    this.$forceUpdate(); // will be update
  });
```

Comment: Awesome, this solves another problem I didn't bring up。thank you ,I learn another trick "this.$forceUpdate(); ",And that says the problem is not "Vue can't detect changes made to an array by directly assigning a value to an index."@skirtle,just should forceupdate manually,thanks both of you,thanks stackoverflow~